# Parsing json with gson and java

Tags: java, json, gson

I am struggling to parse a json output with Java and gson, but I am really stuck.

I would appreciate any suugestion.

This is my sample JSON file:

```
{
"sportId": 29,
"last": 26142386,
"league": [
    {
        "id": 1833,
        "events": [
            {
                "id": 383911973,
                "starts": "2015-01-22T21:00:00Z",
                "home": "America de Natal",
                "away": "Barras",
                "rotNum": "901",
                "liveStatus": 0,
                "status": "O",
                "parlayRestriction": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 383911974,
                "starts": "2015-01-22T21:00:00Z",
                "home": "Baraunas RN",
                "away": "ASSU RN",
                "rotNum": "904",
                "liveStatus": 0,
                "status": "O",
                "parlayRestriction": 0
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My target is to a make a 2-dimensional array (or something similar) of the form:

```
leagueId, eventId, home, away
------------------------------
   1         1       a    b
   .         .       .    .
   .         .       .    .
  etc       etc     etc   etc
```

in order to insert the data in a MYSQL table.

I have write the following classes:

```
public class Fixtures {
int last;
int sportId;
ArrayList<Leagues> league = new ArrayList<Leagues>();

public ArrayList<Leagues> getListOfLeagues() {  
    return league;  
}  

public int getSportId(){
    return sportId;
}

 public int getLast(){
    return last;
 }

}

public class Leagues {
int id;
ArrayList<Events> events;

public int getLeagueId(){
    return id;
}

 public ArrayList<Events> getListOfEvents() {  
    return events;  
 }  

}

public class Events {
int id;
String home;
String away;


public int getEventId(){
    return id;
}

public String getHome() {  
    return home;  
}  

 public String getAway() {
    return away;
 }


}
```

and

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();             
Fixtures fixture = gson.fromJson(jsonsource, Fixtures.class);
System.out.println(fixture.getSportId());
System.out.println(fixture.getLast());

ArrayList<Leagues> Leagues = fixture.getListOfLeagues();
```

Dont know how to proceed :(

Comment: I noticed you're new here, and this is a fantastic job for a first question. My only suggestion would be to be a bit more specific on the problem! You say you're having trouble parsing the json with java and gson, but I think you're not getting errors, just unsure of the best approach to solve your problem. In the future, remember that your problem description is the first step to letting other developers know if they can help you.

Comment: @Alexandros it would seem that you are actually close to achieving what you want to, assuming that the Gson parsing is working properly. Can you clarify what the problem is? Are you unclear on how to interact with the DB or is the problem how to flatten your domain objects into a set of rows in a single table?

Comment: @pens-fan-69, Hello friend. My problem is that I do not know how to flatten my domain object in a single table. I dont know how to iterate correctly through the array to extract the data in a flat table. I am ok with the DB that is not the prob. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The real answer here is to not do it this way.

Have you looked at Hibernate? It's like Entity for C#. It allows you to interact with your relational database as an object oriented entity structure, which is how we're used to thinking about things.

Typically, when you have a set of data as input and need to put that data in a database, you need to make a few considerations:

1. Does my input properly represent how my data is stored?
2. Does my relational model (database) represent how my data is used?
3. If one or both of these is a "no", can I change either of them to make them true?

If your model is good and your input is good (which your input looks fine), then you should have no need to put your data into an intermediate layer, you should be able to loop over the applicable fields and put the data in your database. If you can't do that, I'd recommend restructuring your database. Again, I know this is kind of a sideways answer, but you did ask for suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

Try jackson to parse JSON to java object, you get some help from here where a similar JSON was parsed to couple of java objects.

[JSON parsing example using jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30979270/1129313)

Try it and let me know if you find any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out how to do the iteration:

```
 for (Leagues leg : Leagues) {
        System.out.println(leg.getLeagueId());
        ArrayList<Events> Events = leg.getListOfEvents();
        for (Events event : Events) {
            System.out.println(event.getEventId());
            System.out.println(event.getHome());
            System.out.println(event.getAway());
            System.out.println(event.getStarts());
        }

    }
```

Thanks all.

Comment: If you are using Java 8, you could also take a look at streams to accomplish the same thing with what may be more compact code. However this works just fine as well. Glad you figured it out.